# how to print logs in tomcat servlet application

Tags: java, servlets, tomcat6

I am creating servlet on Tomcat 6.0 in ubuntu 10.04. For printing log I used System.setOut to redirect output.

```
System.setOut(new PrintStream(new File("/tmp/new.log")));

System.setErr(new PrintStream(new File("/tmp/new.log")));
```

I have to use this code in doPost() but when run my application then I am not able to see output thats why temporarily I moved this code in doGet().

When I hit url through browser http://127.0.0.1:8080/hello/hello I am getting following error on browser

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.io.FilePermission /tmp/new1.log read)
    java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:342)
    java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:553)
    java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
    java.lang.SecurityManager.checkRead(SecurityManager.java:888)
    java.io.File.exists(File.java:748)
    HelloWorldExample2.doGet(HelloWorldExample2.java:42)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor32.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:269)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:537)
    org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:301)
    org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:162)**
```

Comment: It seems the user from which you are running server isn't have write permission for /tmp dir

Comment: @org.life.java, Apache Tomcat by default doesn't have root access on tmp in Ubuntu.

Comment: As suggested , why you are trying invent wheel again, go for log4j

Comment: Unrelated to the problem: having servlet classes in the default package is a bad practice. It won't work on every environment.

Answer (score 4):

I'd strongly suggest using a logging framework such as [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/), [SLF4j](http://www.slf4j.org/) or even the Logging classes that come with Java itself.  You're kind of re-inventing the wheel here :)

Answer (score 1):

Use a [Logging Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_logging_framework) such as Java Util Logging or [Log4J](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/).

Answer (score 1):

Since several diffent servlets might be deployed and each of those could be trying to redirect stdout, this is simply not something tomcat can allow you to do (not to mention it already redirects streams for logging, to catalina.out).

So either just filter out what you need out of the tomcat logfile, or assign those streams to some static variables that you can access from the servlet. You need some synchronisation, though I think the I/O classes might be threadsafe. Using a logging framework would make life easier on you, depending on how big of a project this is (anything bigger than a servlet with 2 methods).

Answer (score 1):

Use [slf4j](http://www.slf4j.org/) and [Logback](http://logback.qos.ch/index.html) for your logging needs. You won't regret it since you don't want to reinvent the wheel + you'll have a very customizable solution.